# Terraform s3 backend vs terraform_remote_state

Tags: terraform

According to the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html), to use `s3` and not a local `terraform.tfstate` file for state storage, one should configure a backend more or less as follows:

```
terraform {

  backend "s3" {
      bucket = "my-bucket-name"
      key = "my-key-name"
      region = "my-region"
  }
}
```

I was

- using a local (`terraform.tfstate`) file
- added the above snippet in my `provided.tf` file
- run (again) `terraform init`
- was asked by terraform to migrate my state to the above bucket

...so far so good...

But then comes [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) confusing part about `terraform_remote_state` ...

Why do I need this?

Isn't my state now saved **remotely** (on the aforemenetioned s3 bucket) already?

Comment: I am fairly sure that you are doing a Terraform Remote State already, but with S3 as the backend. When you say "S3 Backend", that is the backend for the remote state.

Comment: This is a ready to use version that handles the full backend setup for you. https://github.com/getstrake/aws-pricing-sheets-addon

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`terraform_remote_state`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) isn't for storage of your state its for retrieval in another terraform plan if you have outputs. It is a [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html). For example if you output your Elastic IP Address in one state:

```
resource "aws_eip" "default" {
  vpc      = true
}

output "eip_id" {
  value = "${aws_eip.default.id}"
}
```

Then wanted to retrieve that in another state:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "remote" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "my-bucket-name"
    key = "my-key-name"
    region = "my-region"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = "${aws_instance.foo.id}"
  allocation_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.remote.eip_id}"
}
```

**edit: If you are retrieving outputs in Terraform > 0.12 you need to include `outputs`**

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "remote" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "my-bucket-name"
    key = "my-key-name"
    region = "my-region"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = "${aws_instance.foo.id}"
  allocation_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs.eip_id}"
}
```

Comment: So if I do not use `outputs` there is no need for remote state?

Comment: Correct, you dont need it unless you are going to retrieve outputs @pkaramol

Comment: It's amazing the number of posts I find where people are calling "backend state", "remote state". As @Brandon says, they are different.

Comment: Make sure include `outputs` when referring to outputs if your terraform is > = 0.12

`data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs.eip_id`

Comment: config block requires a `=` signal.
`config = { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Remote State allows you to collaborate with other team members, and central location to store your infrastructure state.
Apart from that by enabling s3 versioning, you can have versioning for state file, to track changes.